# How to fix the focus being reset to the top the page when the currently focused element is removed using ngIf in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, internet-explorer, wai-aria

I am working on improving the accessibility of an Angular Application. There is a cancel button, if pressed will hide the button and display div with a warning and two buttons, yes and no. If pressed no, the warning disappears and the cancel button re-appears.

I will add a small sample code snippet below. Actual code is a little complex.

```
 <button *ngIf="!hideCancel" (click)="toggleWarning(true)" </button>

 <div *ngIf="hideCancel">
      <p>Are you sure you want to cancel?</p>
 <button> Yes </button>
 <button (click)="toggleWarning(false)"> No </button>
 </div>


 toggleWarning(flag: boolean) {
    if (flag) {
        document.getElementById('someWarning').innerHTML = 'Are you sure you want to cancel?';
    } else {
         document.getElementById('someWarning').innerHTML = '';
    }
    this.hideCancel= !this.hideCancel;
 }
```

When using tab key and when focused on cancel button, when user presses enter key, the cancel button disappears and the below Warning appears. Then Chrome/Firefox, when I press the tab key, focus goes to the "No" button below the Warning as expected. But in IE, focus goes to the top of the page.

I am not getting why it is happening. Is it because the currently focused element(cancel button) is removed from the DOM hence the focus is reset to the top on tabbing?
Please help on how to prevent this in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I suggest trying to set the focus on the element that is displaying on the page before hiding the button and after the 'no' button gets appear then try to set the focus to it may help to fix the issue for the IE browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to this by retaining the tab focus on the next element.

```
<button *ngIf="!hideCancel" (click)="toggleWarning(true);yesBtn.focus()">Cancel </button>
<!-- see how yesBtn reference is used to set the focus-->
 <div *ngIf="hideCancel">
      <p>Are you sure you want to cancel?</p>
 <button #yesBtn> Yes </button>
 <button (click)="toggleWarning(false)"> No </button>
 </div>
```

Checkout the [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-form-7e1zao?file=app/app.component.html).

Comment: it will error as the element I want to focus is not yet present in the DOM.

Comment: @MohammedShirhaan I thought `cancel` button is what that gets hidden on enter press and you want IE to retain that focus right? And why do you want to focus an element which is not in the DOM? Correct me if wrong.

Comment: in my code example, there is a button with ngIf directive and there is a div with ngIf directive, at a time one of them will be available in screen(DOM).When the first button is clicked, the clicked button will disappear and the div(with two addtional buttons) will appear. When 'No' button is clicked, the parent div of this button will disappear along with the two buttons inside(one which was clicked) and the first button without a div will appear.